# Database Dataset errors in form designer view

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm using visual studio 2012, c# and have created several windows form applications but whenever I try to run my program, there is an error with the "designer view":

```
this.employee_DatabaseDataSet = new Form1.Employee_DatabaseDataSet();
this.tblCustLoginBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
this.tblCustLoginTableAdapter = new Form1.Employee_DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.**tblCustLoginTableAdapter();
this.tableAdapterManager = new Form1.Employee_DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters**.TableAdapterManager();
```

It seems to me that there is a problem with my data source but I have started fresh so I don't see what the problem is.

This is the error that comes up:
"The type name Employee_DatabaseDataSet does not exist in the type form1.form1"

Can someone be so kind to help me please? Thanks for reading

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `()` parenthesis pair after `Form1`
Try this :

```
this.employee_DatabaseDataSet = new Form1().Employee_DatabaseDataSet();    
this.tblCustLoginBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
this.tblCustLoginTableAdapter = new Form1().Employee_DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.tblCustLoginTableAdapter();
this.tableAdapterManager = new Form1().Employee_DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work. So I'm going to restart the project again!

Comment: @user3065417: please check and let me know. you should follow the same for all other statements wherever you are accessessing form1 elements